# How to write url's in achor links so doesn't fire errors/warings @ w3c validator

Tags: html, markup, validation

just a simple link with parameters

```
<a href="http://domainame.com/?bla=ble&bli=blo">hey!</a>
```

would make the w3c validator jump two errors, one for the equeal (=) and one for the and (&)

```
Error Line 1, Column 43: reference to entity "bli" for which no system identifier could be generated




This is usually a cascading error caused by a an undefined entity reference or use of an unencoded ampersand (&) in an URL or body text. See the previous message for further details.
Info Line 1, Column 39: entity was defined here
```

How can i write them and get 0 errors/warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equal sign throws no errors. Replace the `&` with `&amp;` like so:

```
<a href="http://domainame.com/?bla=ble&amp;bli=blo">hey!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to escape the characters

For example `=` will be `%3D` and `&` will be `&amp;`

Read more here [HTML url encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)